# Building a Shared Library but linking against a Static One

Tags: makefile, shared-libraries, static-libraries, autotools, configure

I have an Autogen Makefile.am that I'm trying to use to build a test program for a shared library.  To build my test binary, I want to continue building the shared library as target but I want the test program to be linked statically.  I've spent the last few hours trying to craft my Makefile.am to get it to do this.

- I've tried explicitly changing the LDADD line to use the .a version of the library and get a file not found error even though I can see this library is getting built.
- I try to add the .libs directory to my link path via LDFLAGS and still it can't find it.
- I tried moving my library sources to my test SOURCES list and this won't work because executable object files are built differently than those for static libraries.
- I even tried replicating a lib_LIBRARIES entry for the .a version (so there's both a lib_LTLIBRARIES and a lib_LIBRARIES) and replicate all the LDFLAGS, SOURCES, dir and HEADERS for the shared version as part of the static version (replacing *la* with *a* of the form _a_SOURCES = _la_SOURCES.  Still that doesn't work because now it can't figure out what to build.
- My configure.ac file is using the default LT_INIT which should give me both static and dynamic libraries and as I said it is apprently building both even if the libtool can't see the .a file.

Please, anyone know how to do this?

Comment: `prog_LDFLAGS = -static`

Comment: Thank you!  That worked!  Keep the LDADD with the library in .la form (shared) but then forcing static on the LDFLAGS does indeed force a static linking with my library!  Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: .la isn't necessarily a shared library. It's actually a text file containing the locations of static _and_ shared versions of the library, along with some other information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Brett Hale mentions in his comment, you should tell `Makefile.am` that you want the program to be statically linked.

To achieve this you must append `-static` to your `LDFLAGS`.
Changing the `LDFLAGS` for a specific binary is achieved by changing `binary_LDFLAGS` (where binary is the name of the binary you want to build).

so something like this should do the trick:

```
binary_LDFLAGS = $(AM_LDFLAGS) -static
```